# cjpeg fails "unrecognized file input format --- perhaps you need -targa"

Tags: 14.04, command-line, jpeg

I'm using 14.04.1 LTS (server), I have installed the following: libjpeg8 libjpeg62 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-progs libjpeg-turbo-progs

The image file in question returns this with the `file` command (I split into two lines):

```
$ file image.jpg
image.jpg JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, 
comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 100"
```

When I run `cjpeg image.jpg` I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized input file format --- perhaps you need -targa
```

Following the advice, I run cjpeg -targa image.jpg:

```
Invalid or unsupported Targa file
```

Searching google brought up a lot of source code files for various packages that call cjpeg and had bits of the error message in question spread throughout the file but nothing referenced the same error I am getting.

Comment: Can you upload the image somewhere so we can see it? You don't have to, it'll just make this fix easier.

Comment: It is [this image from unsplash.com](http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_522ee1a4293f8_1.JPG)

Comment: See atmaish's comment below for jpegtran command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error simply because you tried to compress an unsupported file (such as a JPG file), from the `cjpeg` man page:

> **cjpeg** compresses the named image file, or the standard input if no file
>      is named, and produces a JPEG/JFIF file on the  standard  output.   The
>      currently supported input file formats are: **PPM** (PBMPLUS color format),
>      **PGM** (PBMPLUS gray-scale format),  **BMP**,  **Targa**,  and  **RLE**  (Utah  Raster
>      Toolkit  format).   (RLE  is  supported  only  if  the  URT  library is
>      available.)

When I try to compress a JPG file I also get the same error:

```
$ cjpeg foo.jpg
Unrecognized input file format --- perhaps you need -targa
```

Actually this is the default error message, see `cjpeg.c`

```c
  switch (c) {
#ifdef BMP_SUPPORTED
  case 'B':
    return jinit_read_bmp(cinfo);
#endif
#ifdef GIF_SUPPORTED
  case 'G':
    return jinit_read_gif(cinfo);
#endif
#ifdef PPM_SUPPORTED
  case 'P':
    return jinit_read_ppm(cinfo);
#endif
#ifdef RLE_SUPPORTED
  case 'R':
    return jinit_read_rle(cinfo);
#endif
#ifdef TARGA_SUPPORTED
  case 0x00:
    return jinit_read_targa(cinfo);
#endif
  default:
    ERREXIT(cinfo, JERR_UNKNOWN_FORMAT);
    break;
  }
```

`JERR_UNKNOWN_FORMAT` is defined in `cderror.h`:

```c
#ifdef TARGA_SUPPORTED
JMESSAGE(JERR_UNKNOWN_FORMAT,
     "Unrecognized input file format --- perhaps you need -targa")
```

Source: http://www.ijg.org/

Comment: So I would need to do a file conversion first? I assumed JPG would be compatible with cjpeg.

Comment: @Brian: your image.jpg is already compressed. Converting this file to another compatible format and re-compress with cjpeg would result in a quality loss.

Comment: @Brian: If your goal was to reduce the size of the jpg file, you can use this kind of command: `convert unsplash_522ee1a4293f8_1.JPG -resize 50% image2.jpg`. I hope I answered your original question

Comment: You did answer it, it was a bad file format. Thank you for the succinct answer.

Comment: @Brian: btw, to use the `convert` utility, install imagemagick: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @SylvainPineau. Like you pointed out, I was using cjpeg to compress a jpeg. For a lossless optimization, I got around by using `jpegtran` which is present in the same package. Here's what I used: `jpegtran -copy none -optimize -progressive old.jpeg > new.jpeg`. Note that -copy none would strip the metadata from the image and -optimize would optimize the Huffman tables and improve compression.